# Document table of contents tree structure on the left

Tags: texmaker

Is there a software for Windows that allows you to see the tree structure of your document, like in word (you see the table of contents on the left) ?
I have Texmaker, but you see only a brief tree structure only on the main file, but not on every file and not all the sections and subsections of the file...

Comment: You should look at the list of LaTeX editor/ide on the website: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides/384

Comment: OK if I look there : Texniccenter, Winedt, Led and perhaps Texstudio. To be checked...

Comment: Codebrowser is great (you set the folding points yourself - which I find far better than any automated approach) http://tibleiz.net/code-browser/

Comment: In winedt, the tree is visible and good.

Comment: I suggest you use [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Kile has a fairly detailed tree structure per document and an overview of all files per project and all files/projects open.

So one tab gives you files/projects:

[image: files/projects]

and another a detailed structure of the current file:

[image: current file]

You can customise this somewhat.

Although code-folding is customisable and you can define custom folds, custom points don't show in the structure. (At least, not for me.)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by so many others, there is [a huge list of Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides/384).

I personally recommend [`TeXnicCenter`](http://www.texniccenter.org/) as it is my favorite IDE and has **everything** I need, including the documet layout you mentioned in your question:

[image]